# One-way sync, no synchronisation of deleted files

Tags: windows, synchronization

Situation:

- Multiple Clients uploading zip files (raw data) to a file server, every night
  (sftp synchronise job)
- A File Server, that stores that zip files
- A Processing Server, this server runs a **special software** that waits for zip
  files in a specific directory, processes that zip files (processed data is stored in a database)
  and than deletes that zip files.
  (it is not possible to modify the software)

The goal is to store the zip files (raw data) on the file server (forever) and to process the **new** files on the processing server.

To achieve that, I set up a **Read Only Samba Share** on the file server and mounted it on the processing server (Windows 7)

Now I am searching for a **One-Way Sync Software** for the processing server, that syncs the zip files from the mounted read only network share to the specific directory. But the requirement is, that the sync software keeps track of the deleted files on the local directory, so it will not sync all the files from the network share on the local directory again.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Should be able to do something similar with a batch script - first copy to your archive location, then move to the processing location. Repeat as frequently as required...

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but that would only relocate the problem, because the clients also work with one-way synchronisation.
When i split up the file server directory in archive and processing location, than the clients would dump me with all their zip-files every night. (because the clients store all their zip files as well)

Comment: Have you tried asking on the site for [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?

Answer (score 0):

Since its tagged windows, I'd suggest using DFS, but if you are stuck with samba (which is obviously not windows) either script the copy or check https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask